# Is nodejs fs.writeFile safe?

Tags: node.js, fs

I'm running a node.js server. I'm logging websocket requests to a file. Do you need to sanitize the requests before calling [`fs.writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) or is it safe to just write the request directly?

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("somefile", websocketrequeststring, somecallback);
```

Comment: To test something like this, because i have no idea what type of data you're packing in websocketrequeststring, is to ask yourself "can a client change this string or not".

If they can, then your answer is without a doubt it needs to be sanitized.  Otherwise, it doesn't.

Comment: @simon Not really. There is no need to sanitize anything for `fs.writeFile`, `websocketrequeststring` could be absolutely anything without causing any issues. If the file is read later then used in output to something else (sent to a database, a browser, etc) it should be escaped properly at that time for whatever context it is output to. Since this is just to be used as log it is actually important not to "sanitize" anything, because you could end up stripping exactly the data you need to analyze to find the cause of an issue later on.

Comment: And then what happens if a client figures out how to send that data to you, and decides to send you a googolbyte of data.

Yeah, have fun as your server is destroyed.

Comment: @simon It's up to the server to limit the size of requests... You shouldn't even be trying to process requests that are anywhere close in size to what you can log.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to sanitize anything for `fs.writeFile`, `websocketrequeststring` could be absolutely anything without causing any issues, and it is arguably important not to manipulate that data since you may need it unaltered for debugging. The only consideration is to make sure you have some sort of log retention/rotation plan so that you don't run out of disk space.

In general you should never "sanitize" output, but you should always escape output using an appropriate strategy. In the case of `fs.writeFile` there are no character sequences that have special meaning, everything is just written to the file as is, so no escaping is needed. If you later decide to make an admin portal where you can view these logs in a browser you would have situations where you need escaping. If you read the file and then output it to a database, you would need appropriate escaping at that time. If you read the file and output it to a browser you would need appropriate escaping which would depend on whether it's being output into HTML or JavaScript.

Sanitizing and validation (not escaping) should be done with input directly, but you probably want to still log the unsanitized input.

Comment: The exception to this, of course, is the **path to the file you're writing** which should absolutely not, ever, be under user control.

Comment: @tadman Yes, good advice. If the path comes from user input there is a major security issue unless very specific sanitization and/or validation are done on the path.